# Deal with encrypted username/email with Laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-passport

I work with an existing application for a client and the username/email are encrypted in the database. I need to do an api for external app/website with Laravel passeport.

App/website will call http://localhost:81/oauth/token, they will send parameters `client_id`, `client_secret`, `username` and `password`.  My problem its  with the `username` parameters, because username are encrypt in my app. How can I encrypt their clear (not encrypted) username with laravel passeport?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look [inside passport](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/7ed1a0b80c1da9a3bf25eb180068ddd005a82068/src/Bridge/UserRepository.php#L39), will note that it looks for existence of the method "findForPassport" inside your model.

Just define the method in your `User` model and apply your decode algorithm before selecting the user in database:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     *
     * @param  string  $username
     * @return null|App\User
     */
    public function findForPassport($username)
    {
        $decoded = my_decode_function($username);

        return $this->where('username', $decoded)
            ->first();
    }
```

Comment: Humm, maybe that could work, but my username is encrypted in the database. I need to encrypt the username, and then check if it match in the database but encryption always generate a differents string...